# Merging of XML Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

Can anyone give me an example of merging the following XML nodes with XSLT?

```
<pre>
    <Table1>
        <VendorID>123456</VendorID>
        <VendorName>StackOverflow Inc</VendorName>
        <Type>ADDRESS</Type>
        <TypeName>Mailing</TypeName>
        <DescriptionType>Main Mailing</DescriptionType>
        <Description>P O Box 01 Manama Bahrain</Description>
        <Online>0</Online>
        <CommodityTypeDesc/>
    </Table1>
</pre>

<pre>
    <Table1>
        <VendorID>123456</VendorID>
        <VendorName>StackOverflow Inc</VendorName>
        <Type>ADDRESS</Type>
        <TypeName>Remittance</TypeName>
        <DescriptionType>Main Remittance</DescriptionType>
        <Description>P O Box 02 Manama Bahrain</Description>
        <Online>0</Online>
        <CommodityTypeDesc/>
    </Table1>
</pre>
```

The resulting XML would need to group the differing address nodes into one parent node for the vendor.

Can you also tell me which XSLT/XML tool you use for this work.

Comment: Thanks #rekaszeru for the format edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following stylesheet groups by `VendorID`. Note that you don't say which elements are part of the address and which aren't. This stylesheet assumes that only `VendorID` and `VendorName` are not part of the address. Edit accordingly.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="byVendor" match="root/pre" use="Table1/VendorID" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root/pre" />
    <xsl:template
        match="root/pre[generate-id() =
                        generate-id(key('byVendor', Table1/VendorID))]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Table1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|VendorID|VendorName" />
            <Addresses>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('byVendor', VendorID)/Table1"
                                       mode="address" />
            </Addresses>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Table1" mode="address">
        <Address>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                 select="*[not(self::VendorID or self::VendorName)]" />
        </Address>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this input:

```
<root>
    <pre>
        <Table1>
            <VendorID>123456</VendorID>
            <VendorName>StackOverflow Inc</VendorName>
            <Type>ADDRESS</Type>
            <TypeName>Mailing</TypeName>
            <DescriptionType>Main Mailing</DescriptionType>
            <Description>P O Box 01 Manama Bahrain</Description>
            <Online>0</Online>
            <CommodityTypeDesc />
        </Table1>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <Table1>
            <VendorID>123456</VendorID>
            <VendorName>StackOverflow Inc</VendorName>
            <Type>ADDRESS</Type>
            <TypeName>Remittance</TypeName>
            <DescriptionType>Main Remittance</DescriptionType>
            <Description>P O Box 02 Manama Bahrain</Description>
            <Online>0</Online>
            <CommodityTypeDesc />
        </Table1>
    </pre>
</root>
```

Produces:

```
<root>
    <pre>
        <Table1>
            <VendorID>123456</VendorID>
            <VendorName>StackOverflow Inc</VendorName>
            <Addresses>
                <Address>
                    <Type>ADDRESS</Type>
                    <TypeName>Mailing</TypeName>
                    <DescriptionType>Main Mailing</DescriptionType>
                    <Description>P O Box 01 Manama Bahrain</Description>
                    <Online>0</Online>
                    <CommodityTypeDesc />
                </Address>
                <Address>
                    <Type>ADDRESS</Type>
                    <TypeName>Remittance</TypeName>
                    <DescriptionType>Main Remittance</DescriptionType>
                    <Description>P O Box 02 Manama Bahrain</Description>
                    <Online>0</Online>
                    <CommodityTypeDesc />
                </Address>
            </Addresses>
        </Table1>
    </pre>
</root>
```

Comment: Impressive work - thanks.  Assumptions in which nodes are part of address are correct - thanks.

Comment: On my implementation I get the correct schema but duplicated, e.g. Table1 node and its children twice.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

XML is actually, as follows, hence why I am getting duplicates:

```
<Vendors>
    <Table1>
        <VendorID>123456</VendorID>
        <VendorName>StackOverflow Inc</VendorName>
        <Type>ADDRESS</Type>
        <TypeName>Mailing</TypeName>
        <DescriptionType>Main Mailing</DescriptionType>
        <Description>P O Box 01 Manama Bahrain</Description>
        <Online>0</Online>
        <CommodityTypeDesc />
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <VendorID>123456</VendorID>
        <VendorName>StackOverflow Inc</VendorName>
        <Type>ADDRESS</Type>
        <TypeName>Remittance</TypeName>
        <DescriptionType>Main Remittance</DescriptionType>
        <Description>P O Box 02 Manama Bahrain</Description>
        <Online>0</Online>
        <CommodityTypeDesc />
    </Table1>
</Vendors>
```

Comment: are you still searching for an answer?